# How to read python dictionary and tuples

Tags: python, parsing, context-free-grammar

Can someone help me read this Python dictionary-tuples?
I am new to python and I can't get much out of it

```
Grammar = {'AB':('S', 'B'), 'BB':'A', 'a':'A', 'b':'B'}
```

Note: 
The grammar is the grammar of a Context Free Grammar.

Comment: What part is confusing you?

Comment: Hmm... it's a dictionary bound to the name `Grammar`, with four keys each mapping to a single character, except one who maps to a two element tuple. We can't tell you much more than that from the information you give us.

Comment: The grammar is supposed to be of the form,

Comment: S->AB \n A->a \n B->b, I can't understand how to convert the above dictionary to what I just described.

Comment: Is "S->AB \n A->a \n B->b" the complete grammar? That dictionary seems...backwards.

Comment: @user2253741 Its not Context Free Grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the dictionary into what you want you can do something like this:

```
>>> from collection import defaultdict
>>> grammar = {'AB':('S', 'B'), 'BB':'A', 'a':'A', 'b':'B'}
>>> tmp_result = defaultdict(list)
>>> def tuplify(val):
...     if not isinstance(val, tuple):
...         val = (val,)
...     return val
... 
>>> for key, value in grammar.items():
...     values = tuplify(value)
...     for val in values:
...         tmp_result[val].append(key)
... 
>>> tmp_result
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['a', 'BB'], 'S': ['AB'], 'B': ['AB', 'b']})
>>> result = {key:tuple(val) for key, val in tmp_result.items()}
>>> result
{'A': ('a', 'BB'), 'S': ('AB',), 'B': ('AB', 'b')}
```

Where the class `collections.defaultdict` is a `dict`-like class, which uses a factory to create a default value when the key is missing. For example writing:

```
>>> D = defaultdict(list)
>>> D[5].append(3)
>>> D[5]
[3]
```

Can be written using normal `dict`s like:

```
>>> D = {}
>>> if 5 in D: # key present, use that value
...     val = D[5]
... else:      # otherwise create a default value and sets it
...     val = list()
...     D[5] = val
... 
>>> val.append(3)
>>> D[5]
[3]
```

The "factory" passed to `defaultdict(factory)` can be any callable that doesn't receive arguments, for example:

```
>>> n = 0
>>> def factory():
...     global n
...     print('Factory called!')
...     n += 1
...     return n   #returns numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
... 
>>> D = defaultdict(factory)
>>> D[0]
Factory called!
1
>>> D[0]   # the keys exists, thus the factory is not called.
1
>>> D[1]
Factory called!
2
>>> D[1]
2
```